Considering Rook in Alien: Romulus, were all Company Science Officers based on the Ash design?
Alien Romulus introduced the android Rook who was described as the Science Officer that appeared to be (controversially) similar to Ash. Were all Company Science Officers based on the Ash design?

I thought the controversy was not about similarity to the character Ash, but using machine learning with CGI to 'act' the role of the android, instead of just hiring an actor.
